# calculating the best speedup

Tags: cpu-architecture

I have been going over a previous exam for my computer architecture course that i got an incorrect answer, how could i calculate the best possibly speedup? 
I understand theres a limit as to how mucha program can be sped up im just unsure of the forumla (he problem is part b). Any help will be upvoted and very much appreciated thanks!

> 1. (6 points) To accelerate an application, two enhancements with the following speedups are proposed:
>      　　Speedup<sub>1</sub> = 25
>      　　Speedup<sub>2</sub> = 15
>
>    Enhancement 1 is usable for 40% of the instructions and enhancement 2 is usable for 30% of the instructions. Two enhancements do not overlap.
>
>    a) What is the speedup if both enhancements are applied?
>
>    b) If you keep improving these two enhancements, what is the best speedup you can reach?

Comment: What does a Speedup of 25 mean?

Comment: Scott, I don't think it matters (I'd guess 25x rather than 25% but I agree it's unclear) because part (b) is what jfisk is looking for help with.

Comment: I think that can be computed by [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Comment: -1: Is it too much work for you to retype the question from that poorly readable photo? What does Speedup=25 mean? 25% more code in the same time? 25 times as fast? 25 times faster?

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan: How can one answer (b) if it isn't clear what Speedup means?  I mean, you can DESCRIBE it, but the question sounds like it is looking for a number.

Comment: @ScottHunter: [speedup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup) is a defined well known concept.

Comment: One can answer (b) by saying: suppose we make both speedups infinite, so that those portions of the code take no time at all; what happens then? This leads to Amdahl's law -- jfisk may either be expected to know it, or to rederive it from first principles (which is very straightforward). The numbers you need for this are the 40% and 30% figures, which are not ambiguous in the way the speedup ones are. (Though the question would be better if it were more explicit that "40% of the instructions" is measuring as a fraction of runtime or assuming all instructions take equal time.)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to memorize a formula, use common sense. Imagine that both portions of speed-up-able code could be sped up *infinitely*: that is, made to take no time at all. What would be left? How much time would it take?

Comment: No, the question states you keep advancing these improvements, and according to [amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), the speed up is limited.

Comment: I was hoping to nudge jfisk towards discovering Amdahl's law for {him,her}self. I'm not sure why you say "no" -- did you perhaps think I was saying "if you speed up those portions of the code infinitely, nothing will be left"? That wasn't my intention at all.

Comment: Then I misunderstood you, and am reverting the comment. please edit the answer, so I can remove the -1 as well.

Comment: I've made a small change which I hope makes it a bit clearer what I'm not saying, while not making it too clear (i.e., giving too much of the game away for the student) what I *am* saying :-).

Answer (score 0):

Let `t` be the total run rime, then:

(a) Since you are not asking for this section, I am giving a full solution, for future readers.

`t' = modified run time = 0.4t / 25 + 0.3t / 15 + 0.3t = 0.336t`, 

Thus, `speedup = t/t' = t / 0.336t ~= 2.97`

(b) The question asks keep advancing THESE speed ups, so you cannot improve the whole program. Then the best speed up you can get, according to **[amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)** is bounded by the sequential, un-improveable part. Amdahl's law says that the maximum speed up will be **`1/SEQUENTIAL_PART`** What is the sequential part in your case? Make sure you understand why.

The idea of amdahl's law is, assuming you can speed up the improved part to infinite speed up, the total speed up will still be bounded by the non-improved part.

Comment: It is usually considered poor style to give full explicit answers to students' homework problems. It is better to provide just enough assistance that they can find the solutions for themselves.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: I accept the comment and editted the answer, to be more informative and less feeding.